# Change the Server Signature in NginX

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I wan to Hide the Server Signature in HTTP 400 Error HTML Error page footer in Nginx. After implementing [Headers-more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) Module. The Server Signature is changed when an HTTP Package is requested:

```
>> curl -I localhost
```

Output

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.abshnb.com/
Server: Abshnb
```

But the HTTP 400 Error HTML Page is still returning the error page with "**nginx**" footer.

Comment: Have you tried an [error_page](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive? Unfortunately, "nginx" word is hardcoded in default error pages: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/15544440425008d5ad39a295b826665ad56fdc90/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c#L36

Comment: Yup I used it and it didn't work. The Error i'm trying to change is 400.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dead simple example of [`error_page`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive where error response is generated by nginx itself:

```
    server {
        listen 8888;
        server_tokens off;
        ...
        error_page 400 502 @error;

        location @error {
            default_type text/html;
            return 200 '<center><h1>$status</h1></center>';
        }

        location = /error400 {
            return 400;
        }

        location = /error502 {
            return 502;
        }
```

Custom error handler:

```
$ http :8888/error400    

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Length: 29
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 08 Feb 2020 11:43:05 GMT
Server: nginx

<center><h1>400</h1></center>
```

Default error handler:

```
$ http :8888/nonexistent

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 162
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 08 Feb 2020 11:47:19 GMT
Server: nginx

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool, Gonna try it and give a feedback.

Comment: It didn't work, the same Default Error page keeps appearing